# A cross-site community promotion advertisement

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

On every Stackexchange site, we decide what gets advertised. Every site can have an advertisement decided by the community. Don't know if we have that advertising here, but we can make use of this advertising to promote **Hinduism.SE** on *other sites*.

[Community Promotion Ads - Official Blog Post by Robert Cartaino](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/)

See the above blog post for more info.

So, we can make one such advertisement for the promotion of our site, and post it on the [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) post of other related sites.

I would like everyone to post an advertisement image, following the specs declared in the official blog post.

Also, please mention on which site it can be used.

Comment: Am already aware about this, but SO does that anyways so we don't have to do it

Comment: @Mr.Alien did you even read the entire post?

Comment: I don't need to, as I said am already aware about this, read the very first line "You may have seen our vote-based advertising for **open source projects** on Stack Overflow" - [Relevant Post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014)

Comment: @Mr.Alien No, its been expanded to promotion of beta sites. Don't you see advertisements for robotics.SE, chem.SE etc?

Comment: You can promote your twitter account but not the site http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/876/advertisement-posted-to-super-user-please-upvote-it-there#comment2166_886

Comment: Also refer http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7438/community-promotion-ads-2014/8079#comment19177_7447

Comment: @Mr.Alien exactly, software recs advertisement _was_ published to super user. And it directly links to the site itself. the site at that time was in beta. That, exactly is what we can do for Hinduism.SE. Do you get my point now? Please ask for further clarification.

Comment: @AwalGarg Advertising Software Recs on Super User makes sense, because Super User is a site about software. It wouldn't make sense to advertise a site about Hinduism on Super User, though, because the two sites have nothing to do with each other. As you say in your post, we can post an ad on "other related sites", but there's the problem - there _aren't_ any other related sites in the SE network! The closest I guess would be [buddhism.se], but they haven't graduated, so they don't have community ads.

Comment: @senshin I know that very well. Thanks. Can you suggest any site where such an ad can be promoted?

Comment: @AwalGarg I don't really use any Hindu forums or anything like that, so I don't have any ideas on that front, unfortunately.